# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage already has a dependency defined for Microsoft.Data.OData

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, dependency-management

I'm using VS2010 with .net 4.0 and have an asp.net mvc project that contains both a web role and worker role for the azure platform.

I'm trying to update my Azure.Storage package and get the following ..

[image]

I've noticed when I look at references in my project and look at the Storage it says it's vers 4.3.0.0.
When I look in my packages.config (for both web and worker) it has..

I can't find any reference to OData.

When I've tried to install or update OData via he package management console it comes up with the same message of "...Storage already has a dependency defined for Microsoft.Data.OData".

I've looked around and couldn't find a posting with the same error and also this is the first time I've tried updating packages so I'm unclear on the overall process.

I have some code in my web role that apparently needs to reference the latest Storage package.

thanks,

Comment: Did you try to totally remove and reinstall all your Azure related packages?

Comment: The solution I found was to get the latest NuGet 'manager'. This was done through Visual Studio.